# How to use Radio button to open local HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am developing a webpage which has radio buttons and pertaining options. On selecting a radio button, I would like to open the corresponding html page. The only solution I found to this problem contained URLs to external webpages, which is something that I don't want.

The HTML code I have right now is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome!</title> 
</head>
<body>

<h2>Select your user classification below:</h2>
<form >
    <input type="radio" name="usertype" value="admin">Admin
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="usertype" value="hod">HOD
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="usertype" value="tstaff">Teaching Staff
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="usertype" value="ntstaff">Non Teaching Staff
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="usertype" value="cr">CR
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="usertype" value="student">Student
    </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

An example: If I select admin and click on submit, I would like to open "admin.html" which is in the same folder as "index.html"

**Solutions using Javascript, JQuery and PHP will be appreciated.**

Comment: *"The only solution I found to this problem contained URLs to external webpages, which is something that I don't want."* - And what happened when you tried that but put your own URLs in? Why do you want to use a radio button plus submit button to navigate to the next page? Wouldn't standard anchors do the same thing more simply?

Comment: I tried using the same code and inserted the relative html link to my page, but it dint work. 
Standard anchors would work brilliantly, thanks for the suggestion (I am a newbie to programming.) 
I will implement anchors for now, but I would still appreciate a solution on how to work with radio buttons for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
   $('form').on('submit',function(){
   event.preventDefault();
       var value=$("input[name=usertype]:checked").val();
    switch(value){
      case "admin":  location.href='admin.html'; break;
   case "hod":  location.href='hod.html'; break;
   case "tstaff":  location.href='tstaff.html'; break;
  
    }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h2>Select your user classification below:</h2>
<form >
    <input type="radio" name="usertype" value="admin">Admin
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="usertype" value="hod">HOD
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="usertype" value="tstaff">Teaching Staff
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="usertype" value="ntstaff">Non Teaching Staff
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="usertype" value="cr">CR
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="usertype" value="student">Student
    </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have this script:

```
$(function(){
   $('form').on('submit',function(){
   event.preventDefault();
   location.href =$("input[name=usertype]:checked").val()+".html";         
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work. It will open a window when the radio button is clicked.  You need to explain what you mean by "open". Navigate to, pop up?  Another tab? new window?

```
<style type="text/css">
    button{border:0;}
    </style>
    <form action="link" target="_blank" ><button type="submit">
    <input type="radio" name="usertype" value="admin">Admin
    </button></form>
```

### What you really wanted:

Add id to radio buttons

```
  <input id="r1" type="radio" name="usertype" value="admin">Admin
  <input id="r2" type="radio" name="usertype" value="hod">HOD
```

Replace

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

With

```
<button type="button" onclick="go()">Submit</button>
```

And the JS code:

```
 function go(){
 if(document.getElementById('r1').checked){location.href='admin.html';}
 else if(document.getElementById('r2').checked){location.href='hod.html';}

 }
```

The property .checked returns true or false.

### What you should really do:

Just use anchors in place of the radio buttons.

Comment: By open, I meant navigate to the relevant page. Anyways I can see that it would open it in a new tab (which would also work). Thank you!